# How to propertly use global prettier config in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, editorconfig

I have globally configured prettier settings in settings.json

```
"prettier.useTabs": false,
"prettier.trailingComma": "none",
"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
"prettier.bracketSpacing": true,
"prettier.singleQuote": true,
"prettier.withNodeModules": true,
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

The problem is I've cloned some opensource repository, that has `.editorconfig` file and project has two spaces, since i have configured onSave action all code is being formatted using prettier settings and ignores `.editorconfig` file settings.

What would be preferred way to configure it, so it use project configuration instead of global and is it even a good idea to use globall prettier settings or instead should i always consider to use project based `.prettier` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default (in "trusted projects"):

```json
"prettier.useEditorConfig": true
```

seems to work neat. It considers local `.editorconfig` overriding prettier (user) settings.

> **prettier.useEditorConfig (default: true)**
>
> Whether or not to take .editorconfig into account when parsing configuration.
> See the [prettier.resolveConfig docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/api.html#prettierresolveconfigfilepath--options) for details.
>
> **Disabled on untrusted workspaces (always false)**

Refs:

- https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettieruseeditorconfig-default-true
- https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#editorconfig

Answer (score 0):

You can install the VS Code [Editorconfig extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig). When this is enabled, it prioritizes the .editorconfig props over VS Code's settings.json.